# Fixed width, variable height image view ios layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, imageview

I want an imageview which has fixed width but variable height. I want to refresh view if the image that I get from the website is heighter than the imageview in storyboard,

This is the view when I use "Scale to Fill".

postimg.org/image/6l1ol2pvz

And this is when I use "Aspect Fill"

postimg.org/image/9duw53q8f/

I want the image to be like in "Aspect Fill" but I can't place the bottom correctly.

Thank you all!

**Solution:**

I gave my image width and height constraints. Then I changed it programmatically. This is the view I wanted and I made it work!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCgHw.png

```
let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgUrl)
let myImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
let aspectRatio = (myImage?.size.height)! / (myImage?.size.width)!

self.postCombineImageViewHeight.constant = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width * aspectRatio
self.postCombineImageViewWidth.constant = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: I think Rob has the right solution. This looks very much like the image overflowing the UIImageView's bounds.

Comment: Your container view which has image should be of type UIScrollView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make height constraint in storyboard then drag and drop constraint IBOutlet in viewcontroller and change his constant when get imageview from website

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution for me. But I want to ask one thing. I set my imageview with alamofireImage library. This is the code I use.

self.postCombineImageView.af_setImageWithURL(imgUrl)

How can I get this image in imgUrl's width and height? If I use these codes with _afsetImageWithURL would it download x2 times?

let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgUrl)
let myImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
let aspectRatio = (myImage?.size.height)! / (myImage?.size.width)!

Answer (score 4):

You should select "clip subviews" in the "Attributes inspector" of this image view in IB (or programmatically set the `clipToBounds` property of the image view).

For example, this is a landscape image shown in a square image view with a content model of "aspect fill", but with "clip subviews" unchecked (i.e. with `clipToBounds` set to `false`):

[image]

(I've added a red `CAShapeLayer` to show where the `frame` of the `UIImageView` is.)

This is the same image view, but with "clip subviews" checked (i.e. `clipToBounds` property is `true`):

[image]

---

Alternatively, you could choose "aspect fit", rather than "aspect fill", in which case the whole image will be visible and not distorted, but you may end up with blank space on the edges of the photo:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it programmatically using `NSLayoutConstraint`

```
self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: myButton,
        attribute: .Width,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: nil,
        attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 200))
```

And for the height you add the variable height

Answer (score 0):

Are you using storyboards? And auto layout?

Try this: place a "vertical distance" constraint between the bottom of the photo and the top of the view that is on the bottom.

Then click the added constraint and on the Attributes Inspector change the relation to "Greater Than or Equal".

This way, the imageView height will adapt to the image content; but if the image's height grows too large, it will stop growing when it reaches the bottom view.

Answer (score 0):

My solution -

1) Provide a height and width constraint for your image.

2) Import AVFoundation kit.

3) Generate a new rect for your image by the following code(fitting it via aspect ratio) -

```
  let boundingRect =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))//width is your fixed width for your image eg. - if your image covers width of your superview. It can be - self.view.frame.width

          let rect  = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(photo.image.size, boundingRect)
```

So now you got your rect -

Now you can change your height constraint by having something like this -

```
imageHeightConstraint.constant = rect.size.height
```